# Is WeakReference a good type in order to reference my custom view inside a static inner class?

Tags: android, weak-references

I am writing a custom view by directly inheriting from the View class, and I am wondering whether I am making a good use of the WeakReference class. First, this is the most relevant part of my class :

```
public class ChessView extends View {

    public ChessView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        /* some code removed */
        invalidateHandler = new InvalidateHandler(this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                     invalidateHandler.sendMessage(invalidateHandler.obtainMessage());
        }

        }).start();
    }

    /* some code removed */

    private static class InvalidateHandler extends Handler {

        public InvalidateHandler(ChessView view){
            relatedChessView = new WeakReference<ChessView>(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            relatedChessView.get().invalidate();
        }

        private WeakReference<ChessView> relatedChessView; 
    };

    private InvalidateHandler invalidateHandler;

}
```

As you can see :

1. I am creating a static inner class, subclass of the Handler class : as the android developpers guide recommands to avoid direct inner classes inside View subclasses
2. The Handler static inner class makes a call to the invalidate() method of my custom ChessView : so I decided to "wrap it" inside a WeakReference, as the android developper guide recommands to avoid hard references on View instances.

So here my questions :

1. Do I avoid memory leaks this way ?
2. Is WeakReference the best type, or should I use a SoftReference instead ?
3. And finally, will the custom view remains on the heap as long as the view is visible (or the related activity active) or may it be collected by the GC before, letting me with a null reference when calling relatedChessView.get() ?

Thanks in advance, and apologizes if my question is bad formulated.

Comment: I don't think it will matter in this case since it's inside a private static class that references it's parent, but it's good practice to *always* check if the `WeakReference` has a referenced object. (i.e. `if(relatedChessView.get() != null) // use relatedChessView.get()`. There's never a guarantee with `WeakReference` that the reference still exists.

Comment: ok, so I'll keep checking this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I avoid memory leaks this way ?

Yes, but this isn't necessary.

> Is WeakReference the best type, or should I use a SoftReference instead ?

`WeakReference` is the way to go in your case. `SoftReference` and `WeakReference` will be both available as long as there is a hard reference pointing to them. If there is no strong reference though, `WeakReference` will more likely to be collected while `SoftReference` will retain your object as long as there is no need to clean up memory (eg. `SoftReference` will stick around longer).

> And finally, will the custom view remains on the heap as long as the view is visible (or the related activity active) or may it be collected by the GC before, letting me with a null reference when calling relatedChessView.get()?

Yes, it will. As i mentioned above `WeakReference` won't be collected while there are any `Objects` holding the contained `Object`'s reference.

**UPDATE:** Fixed the information regarding Weak and Soft references based on @DeeV's answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer : so you say that I don't need WeakReference in order to avoid memory leak ?

Comment: Yes, it isn't necessary, but it won't hurt to leave it in your code, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Ok, so i'll leave it :) Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just to clarify. `SoftReference` won't be collected as long as there's a reference as well (mainly due to the nature of Java garbage collection).  It's only stronger than a `WeakReference` in that a `SoftReference` will stick around when there's no strong reference until memory needs to be cleaned up thus they tend to stick around much longer.  As such, a `WeakReference` in this case is better because there's less likely a chance to reference a dead object which would be bad in the case of a `View`.